# Firefox, Jquery and missing dom elements

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've come across a problem when trying to loop through all divs on a page.

I can grab all the divs using $('div') in IE but not in firefox.

I did the following as a test:-

```
$(function () {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    alert(divs.length)
    var divs2 = $('div')
    alert(divs2.length)
});
```

The output in IE is :-

29 
 29

The output in firefox is :-

29
 1

Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried your code with 3 divs, and I got this - IE: 3 3.  Firefox: 3 4.  Same results with an each().  I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your markup. With 29 divs, I bet you have a missing `</div>` or something somewhere. IE might just count the opening tag; perhaps FF is more strict.

Comment: Firefox, this page you're looking at now: $('div').length == 121. I also would suspect a markup problem, because what you're doing should work just fine, and does work on other pages

Comment: I think it was a problem with the DOM in the end, the problem seemed to be resolved after I wrapped some div tags around a asp.net content place holder in my master page.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you probably have a markup problem.  If it's not that, make sure that you have Firebug - or anything else that might modify the DOM - turned off.

Answer (score -1):

What about `var divs2 = $('div').length;`

Answer (score -1):

$("div") creates new div element, that's why 1 ;)

Try:
alert($("div").length);

Comment: $("div") doesn't create anything.  $("<div>") creates a new element.

Comment: Oh you're right, it doesn't create new div, it creates something else, probably string. Still, it's a single object so that's why output is 1.

Comment: Yeah according to me $("div") should grab an array of all divs from the DOM. Which it does seem to be doing in IE but not in firefox

Comment: Well, I tried var div =  $("div"); and then $("#somediv").append(div); and the output is text 'div'. I tried IE and FF, same result.